# Not able to use datetimepicker in angular2

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am new to Angular 2 and i am trying to implement datetime picker in Angular 2 app which is being downloaded from here [github.com/ng2-ui](https://github.com/ng2-ui/ng2-datetime-picker). Now after downloading the file when I try to run the app using `npm start command`, I am getting an error like this [image]
not able to know what exactly went wrong, have i missed any files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you just need to run:

```
npm install
```

It will inspect package.json, and install all the dependencies - including webpack-dev-server.

Comment: if The webpack-dev-server is a little Node.js then why should i install webpack-dev-server when i have npm alreaqy installed, can you help me understand it